# Create a string containing the selector of a Geb page object

Tags: groovy, geb

I am using Geb with Spock for my automated test. There are multiple dropdowns on the page, and I want to verify the text of all the options. I am using the following to grab the text, and it is working

```
String actualtext = "";
List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#dateFormat"))
        for(WebElement ddoptions : options) {
            actualtext = ddoptions.getText();
        }   
System.out.println(actualtext)
```

For each of these dropdowns, I have created a page object

```
modalDateDropdown {$("#dateFormat")}
```

I want to create a method where I can pass in the Geb page object, and it will return the option text based on the object I pass in. I am unsure how to use the page object and create a string that contains the page object selector (#dateFormat).

I have tried to just pass the page object, but that doesn't work as it isn't the value of the selector

```
public void verifyDropDownOptions(def object) {
    System.out.println(object)
    String actualtext = "";
    List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(object))
    for(WebElement ddoptions : options) {
        actualtext = ddoptions.getText();
    }
    System.out.println(actualtext)
}

verifyDropDownOptions(modalDateDropdown)
```

Answer (score 0):

I over complicated the scenario. The solution is a simple assert on the text of the geb page object, with each option separated by \n

assert modalDateDropdown.text() == "MM/DD/YYYY\nDD/MM/YYYY"

Answer (score 0):

public void verifyDropDownOptions(Navigator dropdownobject, List itemsList) {

```
items { find('option') } // Assuming options are with 'option' tag in HTML
assert items*.text() == itemsList
```

}

verifyDropDownOptions(modalDateDropdown , ["option1","option2"])